# jQuery: use filter(), but work with both results

Tags: jquery, filter

In jQuery, `filter()` reduces your result to those elements that fulfill a certain condition.

This splits the list in two parts. Working with the "good half" of the elements is easy:

```
$("some selector").filter(function() {
  // determine result...
  return result;
}).each( /* do something */ );
```

But how can I work with the "other half" of my elements, too - but without doing the equivalent of *this*:

```
$("some selector").filter(function() {
  // determine result...
  return !result;
}).each( /* do something else */ );
```

Basically, I'd like to feed two separate `/* do something */` parts to a single filter. One for those that match, and one for the others - without having to filter twice. Am I missing a jQuery function that does this?

---

P.S.: I guess I could do:

```
$("some selector").each(function() {
  // determine result...
  if (result)
    /* do something */
  else
    /* do something else */
});
```

But I was hoping for something nicer.

Comment: I'm thinking it'll be `each()`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nZtRF/ One thing perhaps worth noting is that with the `not()` method, performance degrades exponentially as the number of elements increases. For smaller quantities, it is trivial. For large quantities, you will get better performance using an `if()` statement in the filter. See test at jsfiddle link above, and mess around with quantities.

Comment: @patrick: Very true. That's a serious drawback. :-\

Comment: Title looks pretty descriptive to me and the tags are where they belong.

Comment: @Justin Johnson: The *title* is what Google will display prominently, not the tags. I don't think this edit was a substantial improvement, I'm going to roll it back. Also, this question is not at all about JavaScript, it's specifically about jQuery. Please don't make edits solely based on pure personal preference without adding anything of weight.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about Google's titles. It will display the relevant information regardless.  It's not about personal preferences, it's about maintaining organization and consistency. Most titles aren't phrased in a tag-centric form, and when they are, they tend toward uselessness and redundancy.  Also, this question has to do with jquery, which is JavaScript, a predominate factor of this discussion.  The tag was relevant. If you don't like that, I don't really care; it's your question after all.

Comment: @Justin Johnson: Well, I do care what Google would present, and a self-contained title is worth a lot. If you don't really care, why did you make the edit in the first place? I believe I'm long enough around this site to know what I'm doing, and I also edit many questions myself. But generally I leave those that are in good shape alone, even if I disagree with the wording of the title. Because it's *their* question, after all.

Comment: Your tenure on this site is irrelevant compared to mine. If you'd care to read my last comment closely, my point was that I don't care enough to bicker with you about this because it's your question. I made my suggest via edit, you didn't like it, so there's nothing to be done about it. Move on.

Comment: @Justin: Your're missing the point. Next time make your "suggestions" via the comments. Editing other people's questions without making them *substantially* better is rude and disrespectful, SO has a concept of question ownership for a reason. Go ahead, improve my grammar or spelling, I will even thank you for it. Change title or wording just because you happen to have different preferences and I will be offended. Simple enough concept, no?

Comment: @user113716 that jsfiddle link clearly shows the performance difference between if and not. `not()` may be beautiful but it's ugly under the hood!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method recommended by Kobi in plugin form:

```
$.fn.invert = function() {
  return this.end().not(this);
};

$('.foo').filter(':visible').hide().invert().show();
```

Note that `invert()` will not add a new element to the jQuery stack but replace the last one:

```
$('.foo').filter(':visible').invert().end(); // this will yield $('.foo'), not $('.foo:visible')
```

**Edit:** changed `prevObject` to `end()` at Tomalak's suggestion.

Comment: Sweet. :-) I really like that one.

Comment: My code cannot be chained, and this seems to get around that very nicely. +1

Comment: Wouldn't `end()` be better than `prevObject`? `prevObject` means that I must filter in the immediately preceding step, while `end()` refers to the "most recent filtering operation" according to the docs, which means it can be several steps back.

Comment: `prevObject` is the last jQuery object in the stack, which is the result of the last traversal-type operation. (Actually, `end()` is defined as `function() {return this.prevObject || jQuery(null);}`.)

Comment: `end()` might be more future-proof though, as `prevObject` is an internal feature, while `end()` is part of the API.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The API argument a good one, I'd go for `end()`, then.

Comment: I think it does not get much better than this. Nice solution, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

I usually use [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) for this - it can take an array of elements and remove them from your selection, leaving you with the complement:

```
var all = $("some selector");
var filtered = all.filter(function() {
  // determine result...
  return result;
});
var others = all.not(filtered);
```

Comment: Nice one. I was not aware that `not()` works this way, too. +1

Answer (score 1):

You might try your hand at writing a jQuery plugin to do this. Check out the code of the *filter* function, and come up with something that does more precisely what you want. It could be something like:

```
$("some selector").processList(predicate, successCallback, failureCallback);
```

Then you would pass in three callbacks: one that evaluates an object to see if it matches the filter selection (you could also accept a selector string, or the like); one that handles objects that match the selection, and another that handles objects which don't match.

Comment: Yeah, something like this is what I have in mind. :) Won't be too complicated, but I did not want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm not sure if any such thing exists, already. If you need help figuring out how to write the plugin, let us know =)

Comment: Thanks. ^^ I think the plugin that would be able to do this is a no-brainer. I'm just trying to make sure I'm not missing something clever that is built into jQuery already.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is any nicer, but using `filter()` you could do something like:

```
var $others = $();

var $filtered = $('div').filter(function() {
    if(! your filter test) {
        $others.push(this);
    } else {
        return true; 
    }
});

alert($others.length);
alert($filtered.length);
```

**EDIT:**

At first I tried it starting with an empty jQuery set `$()`, and then using `add()` to populate it with the non-filter results, but couldn't make it work.

**EDIT:**

Updated to use push directly on an empty jQuery object as suggested by **Tomalak**.

Comment: Hm, that would be one way to do it. Not exactly smooth, but workable. :) +1 (PS: jQuery is an array, you can use `push()` on it directly)

Comment: Thanks, yeah, it would be a little nicer if I knew a better way to populate the `others` jQuery set within the filter.

Comment: @Tomalak - just noticed your comment about using `push()` directly on the jQuery object. Makes sense, so I updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Small issue with `$()` - it contains the document object, so it is not empty. `$(null)` would be a *really* blank jQuery object.

Comment: @Tomalak - It did prior to version 1.4. From the docs: *As of jQuery 1.4, calling the jQuery() method with no arguments returns an empty jQuery set.* Still, the `not()` solution above ( and the plugin version ) is looking pretty slick.

Comment: Oh I see. I've tested with 1.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.if = function(cond, ontrue, onfalse) {
  this.each(function() {
    if (cond.apply(this)) ontrue.apply(this);
    else onfalse.apply(this);
  });
};

$('some selector').if(function() {
  // determine result
}, function() {
  // do something
}, function() {
  // do something else
});
```

I'm not sure it is much more readable than putting an if inside an each manually, though.

Comment: You'd have to add the index as an argument to `cond.apply()` since jQuery itself feeds the current index to filter functions. And you'd have to add type checks for the `cond, ontrue, onfalse` arguments, obviously. Other than that, this is what I had in mind. Once you chain 5 methods in jQuery, readability suffers anyway. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.  I see you are leaning toward what I was going to suggest:

```
$("some selector").each(function() { 
  if ($(this).is(SOMEFILTER)) { 
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something  
  }
  // continue with things that apply to everything
});
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more jQuery-style, method chaining solution; but `each()` would work, technically. PS: If the filter result is not determinable by a jQuery selector, you can't use `is()`, unfortunately.