# Find td value in table using drop down filtering in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, filtering

http://medfor.petersenuploads.co.uk/product.php/698/2/clear-ps-honey-jar-with-metal-screw-cap

There is currently a set of dropdowns in the middle of the screen and also a tab (Full Product List). If you click one of the products in the full product list, it updates the dropdown lists. This includes a hidden field (Items per case)

What I  want to do, is grab the value of Items Per Case (from the table) based on the 3 selected dropdowns. For instance:

Select 100ml, Sterile R, No label - this matches the 2nd row in the table. I want to grab the value of 'Items per case' from the table so that I can set the hidden dropdown (items per case) and get the correct product to add to the basket.

The code that does this is in script.js

```
// Handles changing any drop downs in the product selection area and updates the choosen item based on label names and field values.
$('.product-options select').change(function() {
    $('p.selection-item').text("");
    $('#selection-name').text($('header>h1').text());
    $('.product-options select').each(function (i) {
        $('p.selection-item').append($("label[for='"+$(this).attr("id")+"']").text() + " " + $('option:selected', this).text(), "<br />");

        var tableRow = $(".product-table td").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() == "50";
            //Needs to match against all drop down values
        }).closest("tr");
        console.log(tableRow);
    });
    $('div.product-selection h2').removeClass('noshow');
    $('div.product-selection p').removeClass('noshow');
    recalcPrice($('#pid').val());
});
```

I need to filter the table to get a single row out and then grab the value of the penultimate column. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the columns / td placement is static, you can do the following.

```
var tableRow = $(".product-table tbody tr").filter(function() {
            var
                cap = $("#capacity :selected").text(),
                ster = $("#sterility :selected").text(),
                lbl = $("#labeltype :selected").text();
            return $(this).find("td").eq(0).text() == cap && $(this).find("td").eq(1).text() == ster && $(this).find("td").eq(2).text() == lbl
        });
```

If the columns / td placement is dynamic, you can do the following.

```
var tableRow = $(".product-table tbody tr").filter(function() {
            var arr = [],
                cap = $("#capacity :selected").text(),
                ster = $("#sterility :selected").text(),
                lbl = $("#labeltype :selected").text();
            $.each($(this).find("td"), function(){
               arr.push($(this).text());//there was a parenthesis missing here.
            });
            return $.inArray(cap, arr) != -1 && $.inArray(ster, arr) != -1 && $.inArray(lbl, arr) != -1;
        });
```

Comment: The first piece of code works, but the second doesn't. Can't see why - doesn't throw an error. When I return a <tr>, how do I grab the 4th <td> from the row? I've seen code a little bit like $(tableRow, tr) but can't find reference to it anywhere. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: There was a parenthesis missing in the second option. Please check that code again.

Comment: To grab the 4th `td` in a `tr`, you can use `tableRow.find("td:nth-child(4)")` or `tableRow.find("td").eq(3)` (`.eq()` is zero based).

Comment: OK. The dynamic version now works but when I try to grab tableRow.find("td").eq(3).text(); it's empty?

Comment: Did you try a `console.log(tableRow)` to see what was selected? If an element was selected, then do a `console.log(tableRow).find("td").eq(3)` to see what is selected. Let me know what you find (or if you find anything with this).

Comment: To see it in action - http://medfor.petersenuploads.co.uk/product.php/698/2/clear-ps-honey-jar-with-metal-screw-cap

Comment: Out of interest, as we're using filter, will it return a full row? tableRow.find("td") returns something (not undefined) but length:0

Comment: Is it something to do with the prevObject? This is what appears in the console.log. Looking at this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798542/jquery-use-filter-but-work-with-both-results

Comment: The website that you linked to has errors in it. I am not sure if that is going to affect the testing on my side or not.

Comment: I've updated our chat. I'll also look at the validation errors.