# Get opposite/inverse of jQuery .filter() results

Tags: jquery, filter, inverse

I have a`.filter` function, which works and marks all parents of `<td>` that contain an input field in red.

However, I need the exact opposite. So return all fields that don't contain `<input`.
I tried `if ($(this).html().indexOf('<input') == -1) {` but that just marks all rows somehow.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ListView1_itemPlaceholderContainer table table table td").filter(function (index) {
            if ($(this).html().indexOf('<input') > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }).closest('div').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Here's my HTML

```
 <div id="ListView1_itemPlaceholderContainer" style=
  "font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #333333;">
      <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 71px"><img id="ListView1_userInfo1_0_ImageUser_0" src=
            "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/13/6GA5kEu6_normal.png" style=
            "height:65px;width:65px;" /></td>

            <td style="vertical-align: top">
              <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td><img id="ListView1_userInfo1_0_Imagebg_0" src=
                            "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/13/1402427948" style=
                            "height:64px;width:251px;" /><br />
                            <span id="ListView1_userInfo1_0_LabelName_0">dfgdfg</span>
                            &nbsp; @<span id=
                            "ListView1_userInfo1_0_LabelUserName_0">dfgdfg</span></td>

                            <td style="text-align: right"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-size:10px">Follower-<span id=
                    "ListView1_userInfo1_0_LabelFollower_0">4578</span> &nbsp; ,
                    Following-<span id=
                    "ListView1_userInfo1_0_LabelFollowing_0">1654</span></span></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td><span id="ListView1_userInfo1_0_LabelAbout_0"></span></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table><br />
    </div>

    <div style="background-color: #EEEEEE;color: #333333;">
      <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 71px"><img id="ListView1_userInfo_1_ImageUser_1" src=
            "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/12/ECWtACTn_normal.jpeg" style=
            "height:65px;width:65px;" /></td>

            <td style="vertical-align: top">
              <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td><img id="ListView1_userInfo_1_Imagebg_1" src=
                            "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/37/pTBlAXSm.jpeg"
                            style="height:64px;width:251px;" /><br />
                            <span id="ListView1_userInfo_1_LabelName_1">dfgdfgd</span>
                            &nbsp; @<span id=
                            "ListView1_userInfo_1_LabelUserName_1">dfgdfgdf</span></td>

                            <td style="text-align: right"><input type="submit" name=
                            "ListView1$ctrl1$userInfo$ButtonFollow" value="Follow" id=
                            "ListView1_userInfo_1_ButtonFollow_1" style=
                            "height:100px;width:100px;" /></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-size:10px">Follower-<span id=
                    "ListView1_userInfo_1_LabelFollower_1">4622</span> &nbsp; ,
                    Following-<span id=
                    "ListView1_userInfo_1_LabelFollowing_1">4007</span></span></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td><span id="ListView1_userInfo_1_LabelAbout_1"></span></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table><br />
    </div>
  </div>
```

I also check out this post [jQuery: use filter(), but work with both results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798542/jquery-use-filter-but-work-with-both-results) as suggested by commenter.

And tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.invert = function () {
            return this.end().not(this);
        };

        $("#ListView1_itemPlaceholderContainer table table table td").filter(function (index) {
            if ($(this).html().indexOf('<input') > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }).invert().closest('div').css('background-color', 'red');
    });

</script>
```

But that also makes all rows red.

Comment: If you want the opposite, just change `true` to `false`?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798542/jquery-use-filter-but-work-with-both-results) which shows how to add an invert function.

Comment: @FelixKling that does not seem to work on my HTML.

Comment: Ah, I guess you need `return true;` somewhere as well. Anyways, the problem is that your "rows" are actually divs and each "row" contains at least one `td` that does not contain an `input`. You have to narrow down the selector more to a specific cell.

Comment: @Mottie thanks, updated my answer with changes made there..but again: all rows are then red.

Comment: @FelixKling not sure what you mean by 'somewhere'. And yes, the code is messy...not my own code unfortunately ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) along with [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ListView1_itemPlaceholderContainer table table table td").not(':has(input)').closest('div').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: @Flo Try `$("#ListView1_itemPlaceholderContainer td:not(:has('input'))")
    .closest('td').css('background-color', 'red')` http://jsfiddle.net/q9othg59/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should accept Arun's answer. The problem is that indexOf returns the index of the first match char http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp, and in your case it will be 0, so the condition *> 0* won't apply. Also for what concerns *== -1* coloring all the rows, better apply your function to tr instead of td

You can change your function to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ListView1_itemPlaceholderContainer table table table tr").filter(function (index) {
            if ($(this).html().indexOf('<input') > -1) {
                return true;
            }
        }).closest('div').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

to mark the rows with *input* to red, or invert the condition to do the opposite. Or better yet
use a different selector as suggested by Arun.

Fiddle for marking red the row with *input* http://jsfiddle.net/q9othg59/2/
and fiddle for the opposite http://jsfiddle.net/q9othg59/4/