# Jquery won't find double Classnames

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
if ($(".event_list")[0]){
if($(".event_list").find(".type").length == 0 && $(".event_list").find(".sold").length == 0) {
   $(".event_list").click();
}
} else {
    $('#something').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
}
```

I tried my code like this, but the HTML element is called:

```
<span class="type sold">Verkocht</span>
```

I'm not sure why it won't work

this is the whole .event-list:

```
<div class="event_list" data-url="/tickets/205511/2b39e0c726/masters-of-hardcore-20-years-of-rebellion" itemprop="tickets" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
        <div class="description">
            <span class="row-label">
                2 e-tickets                    &nbsp;·&nbsp;
                                        <span class="type sold">Verkocht</span>
                                </span>
            <span class="value">
                <a href="/tickets/205511/2b39e0c726/masters-of-hardcore-20-years-of-rebellion" itemprop="offerurl">
                    Masters of Hardcore - 20 Years of Rebellion
                                                – Regular Ticket
                                        </a>
            </span>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Define "won't work". jQuery certainly doesn't have any problem finding that span using the selectors you've shown. Each of them will find the span.

Comment: I mean: What do you expect to have happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It clicked on the `div` when the if is commented out of the code, but when I actually implement it, it won't work... for example: The `div` was linking to certain content, but there are more div's with the `classname: .event_list`, 
But i wan't the script to only click on the `event_list without the span type sold`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you want is your if-statements to filter your $(".event_list") selection of elements. What your code does instead is either click *all* ".event_list" elements, or click nothing depending on the following:

- if there exists at least one event_list with any children,
- and there exists at least one event_list (whether the same list or a different one) that has a ".type" child
- and if at least one of those or a different event_list has a ".sold" child,

then click all,
else click none and do this:

```
$('#something').click(function() {
location.reload();
```

So I think you're asking for something like this:

```
   var soldtypes = $(".event_list").has(".type").has(".sold").click();
```

For example:

```
  <div class = "event_list">
    <span class="type sold">both</span>
  </div>
  <div class = "event_list">
    <span class="sold type">both</span>
  </div>
  <div class = "event_list">
    <span class="type">one</span>
  </div>
  <div class = "event_list">
    <span class="sold">one</span>
  </div>
  <div class = "event_list">
    <span class="somethingelse">none</span>
  </div>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
   var soldtypes = $(".event_list").has(".type").has(".sold");
   soldtypes.css("background-color","red");
  </script>
```

This will select only the top two event_lists and highlight them in red, because  only they contain spans with both classes.

EDIT:

To select the inverse, you can use

```
.not(":has('.type')");
```

[Get opposite/inverse of jQuery .filter() results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308761/get-opposite-inverse-of-jquery-filter-results)

For example, with the previous html, this script will highlight all except for the top two event_lists.

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   var non_types = $(".event_list").not(":has('.type')");
   var non_solds = $(".event_list").not(":has('.sold')");
   non_soldtypes = non_types.add(non_solds);
   non_soldtypes.css("background-color","red");
  </script>
```